# Cannot see rightBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have in one of my `UIViewControllers` a custom `UINavigationBarController` embedded in a `UITabBarNavigationController`. However, I'm unable to see the rightBarButtonItem in my navigationBar.

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
-> Bool {
    /**Setup UITabBarController*/
    let window = UIWindow.init()
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()

    return true
}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        // Setup viewControllers
        let navController = CustomNavigationController()
        navController.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
        viewControllers = [navController]      
    }
}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.app093DA5
        let rightBarButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
        rightBarButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuWhite"), for: .normal)
        rightBarButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: rightBarButton)
    }

    @objc private func rightBarButtonAction(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, the usage of the navigation bar will be by addressing the `navigationBar` and it's `topItem` (and **not** the `navigationItem`) as follow:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

This will work in a project when someone used main Nav object for the entire app but using the `navigationBar` initially.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a button on the navigation bar of `UINavigationController`, but it doesn't work like that.

`UINavigationController` needs a `UIViewController` to display `UIButton` on the screen.

You can read more about it here:

- [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

You have to add a `UIViewController` to display the button:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        // Setup viewControllers
        let navController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        navController.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
        viewControllers = [navController]      
    }
}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.app093DA5
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let rightBarButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        rightBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menuWhite"), for: .normal)
        rightBarButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButton)
    }
}
```

Try this if it works.

**Edit:**

I used the same code above except a small change:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let rightBarButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        //rightBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menuWhite"), for: .normal)
        rightBarButton.setTitle("Home", for: .normal)
        rightBarButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        rightBarButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButton)
    }
}
```

And the output is :

[image]

Comment: I have tried your suggestion yet the UIBarButtonItem is not showing up